# Rest template is throwing resulted in 408 (REQUEST_TIMEOUT); invoking error handler

Tags: spring-mvc

I am trying to upload a heavier file (50mb) from FE and it is storing to database properly. While getting request from BE to FE using rest template , i am getting 
**raised org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 408 REQUEST_TIMEOUT**

I have tried using the code in my rest proxy :

```
    SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory simpleRequestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();

    simpleRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(2000);
    simpleRequestFactory.setReadTimeout(900000);
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(simpleRequestFactory);
    RestProxy restproxy = new  RestProxy();
    restproxy.setRestTemplate(restTemplate);
    return restproxy;
```

But it did not resolve the issue. Any advise?

Comment: It's unclear: do you own the server, or are you just developing a client to the server?

Comment: From server i meant to say the FE and client is BE. it is jboss.